# Detecting when a key is pressed and break when another key is pressed[Python]

Tags: python, module, keyboard

So I'm making a game without PyGame, and I want to add a section where you try to press the correct keyboard letters given the "number" of the letter, which would mean A - 1, B - 2, C - 3, etc. I want to make it so you can't mash every key, so I added a counter. However - the counter doesn't work. Help!

```
def keyboardpart(l,x,num):
    for i in range(num):
        keypress = False
        c = 0
        dn = random.randint(0,25)
        var = l[dn]
        print(dn+1)
        flag1 = False
        start = time.time()
        while time.time()-start < x:
            if keypress and not keyboard.is_pressed(var):
                if c > 3:
                    break
                c+=1
            elif keyboard.is_pressed(var) and not keypress:
                keypress = True
        print(keypress,c)
        if not keypress:
            print("Sorry, you missed that key.")
            flag1 = True
            break
    if flag1:
        keyboardpart(l,x,num)
```

Comment: How could `c > 3` ever be true if you set `c = 0` within the same loop? Did you mean to declare it outside of the loop?

Comment: I'm using the c = 0 for every distinct letter, so every time I loop I choose another letter that the player has to type. The while loop is there as a timer that the player gets to try to type. However, I want it to basically count every time another key is pressed and when that is over 3 to break the while loop and restart.

Comment: Never mind, my mistake.

Answer (score 0):

Check if any keys are pressed then check if the target key is pressed. Also wait until all keys are released before retry.

Try this code:

```
import random, keyboard, time

l = [chr(65+i) for i in range(26)]  # A-Z

def keyboardpart(l,x,num):
    for i in range(num):
        keyboard.is_pressed(65)  # process OS events
        while len(keyboard._physically_pressed_keys): pass # wait until keys released
        keypress = False
        c = 0
        dn = random.randint(0,25)
        var = l[dn]
        print(dn+1, l[dn])
        flag1 = False
        start = time.time()
        while time.time()-start < x:
            if len(keyboard._physically_pressed_keys):  # any key down
               if keyboard.is_pressed(var):  # check target key
                   keypress = True
                   break
               else:  # wrong key
                   c+=1
                   if c >= 3: break   # allow 3 tries
                   while len(keyboard._physically_pressed_keys): pass # wait until keys released
               print(keypress, c)
        print(keypress,c)
        if not keypress:
            print("Sorry, you missed that key.")
            flag1 = True
            break
             
    if flag1:
        keyboardpart(l,x,num)
        
keyboardpart(l,100,4)
```